# Setting up the limits for a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to set up this double integral where :

$
\begin{array}{l}
 \int {\int {(1 + y)\,dxdy} } \, \\ 
 D:x^2  + y^2  - 2y \le 0 \\ 
 y < x^2 \,,\,x \ge 0 \\ 
 \end{array}
$

First thought is switching to polar coordinates, but then I got kinda stuck, any ideas ?

Let $x=r\cos\theta , y=r\sin\theta \Rightarrow 
r \le \sin\theta
$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with Cartesians.  The key is to draw a picture.   The region $D$ is inside the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2 = 1$ and below the parabola $y=x^2$.  Note that the circle and parabola intersect at the origin, and at

$$y+y^2-2 y=0 \implies y=1 \implies x=\pm1$$

The parabola will be above the circle in $D$.  Thus, the integral is

$$\int_{0}^1 dx \, \int_{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{x^2} dy \, (1+y) $$

Comment: To add to this: Once you have the picture it should be clear (after thinking for a moment) why polar coordinates would be a bad idea: the right boundary of $D$ does not have an obvious parametrization in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.  Also the integrand becomes a bit uglier in polar coords.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Cartesian Coordinates: Note: $x \geq 0$.

$I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \int_{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{x^2} (1+y)dydx$